# Capturing record events without triggers

Tags: trigger, database, automation, crud

Is there any way other than `Apex Trigger`/`Process Builder`/`Workflow` to capture record events programmatically? Does Salesforce have any sort of `CRUD` event publisher that can be somehow subscribed to?

My requirement is simple: do X when object Y is inserted/updated/deleted. However both X & Y are dynamic, and it is not possible to create a new trigger every time Y changes.

The problem is, my client has an existing, fragile solution in place that is tightly integrated with triggers and workflows. But my solution needs to detect CRUD events and act upon them in its own thread.

Comment: You can use triggers (OK you have to create one per object type)  to call whatever Apex handling framework you want to build (using the base SObject type) and that framework can be controlled by configuration such as JSON. But I think you need to explain what you mean by "dynamic" and also explain what logic are you looking to build to get a good answer here.

Comment: Did you think about leveraging the metadata API somehow for this?

Comment: @SebastianKessel do you mean to create triggers via the API? As per my requirement it is not possible for me to create new triggers.

Comment: I was not necessarily saying that. Why are triggers not available? You have not explained why.

Comment: I appreciate trying to break down the problem, but let's stick to the question. I cannot create new triggers because my client doesn't want them. They have an existing, fragile solution in place that is tightly integrated with triggers and workflows. But my solution needs to detect CRUD events and act upon them in its own thread. Of course this is my ideal route. If there is no solution here then I have to look into a suboptimal plan B (which I already know about).

Comment: @KeithC I hope above explanation helps. Basically I cannot create new triggers. That is the main requirement here.

Comment: Tricky indeed on the platform. Kicking of some asynchronous Apex gets you a separate thread (and transaction) but you would likely hit limits such as the Apex Flex Queue size (apart from having to convince yourself and your client that adding the calls to queue the work will cause no harm). If your client could afford it, [Heroku Connect](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/my-week-with-heroku-connect/) (or other replication tools) would allow you to move the problem off platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple options:

- Use an out of the box `Syndicated Feed` via `Site` by [Adding a Feed to Your Force.com Site](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/adding-a-feed-to-your-force-com-site).
- Roll your own authenticated feed via `Visualforce Page` using the [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/).

The above should give you insight into **C**reate, **U**pdate, and **D**elete. Tracking **R**ead access is trickier. As long as your API Version is 28+, you can query for `LastViewedDate` in your feed. I am not sure how that will integrate with your `Syndication Feeds` if you take the `Site` approach.

You can probably set this all up on one `Visualforce Page` with something like the following:

```
public PushTopic topic { get; private set; }
public FeedController()
{
    String sObjectType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sObjectType');
    String operation = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('operation');
    String topicName = sObjectType + '_' + operation;
    if (Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType) == null) return;

    List<PushTopic> topics = [SELECT Id FROM PushTopic WHERE Name = :topicName];
    if (!topics.isEmpty()) { topic = topics[0]; }
    else
    {
        topic = new PushTopic(Name=topicName, ApiVersion=36);
        String baseQuery = 'SELECT Id FROM ' + sObjectType;
        if (operation == 'create')
            topic.Query = baseQuery + ' WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY';
        else if (operation == 'update')
            topic.query = baseQuery + ' WHERE LastModifiedDate = TODAY';
        else if (operation == 'delete')
            topic.query = baseQuery + ' WHERE IsDeleted = true ALL ROWS';
        insert topic;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution has to work with or without a Site, without user interaction. But I can see where you are going with this. Basically subscribe to all records, and have the CUD events streamlined through Feeds -right? But doesn't this require creating a Feed for every record in the system? So if the client chooses to perform an Apex-defined action on update of any Account or Contact the corresponding Feeds must already exist. Is that right?

Comment: do Chatter Feeds help here?

Comment: @crop1645 you can track updates that way, definitely. Similar idea.

Comment: @Mossi Were you able to pursue the `Streaming API` at all? It seems like it should work, but I haven't tried it in this level of depth.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I know I haven't provided much insight about my business needs, but there are several issues with using the Streaming API for me: 1) there is a limit of 40-50 PushTopics and 1000 subscribers per org, 2) PushTopics don't return prior values like `Trigger.old` does, 3) staying tuned to PushTopics requires a VF page (I may be able to use a sidebar VF component but even then it won't work in LEX). I also remember reading somewhere that each PushTopic is valid for 24 hours only? I may be wrong.

Comment: @Mossi It is going to be the only way, it sounds like. You only need 3 Push Topics per object the way I outlined above, and if you have the means you could develop one java client to subscribe to the feeds and push the data out that way. Just a thought. It kind of sounds like you have too many constraints and it's making your project impossible.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Well it seems the Streaming API is useful for just a few one-off scenarios as opposed to something a scalable solution can rely on. I am concluding that what you have provided are indeed the only alternatives and thus answer my original question. Thanks!

Comment: @Mossi Sounds like a tricky client. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.